# How to determine the current frequency count of a specific property's same value within an array of key-value pairs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, foreach, reduce

Given is an array of objects. Each object has 3 key-value pairs.

```
const array = [                       // overall frequency/occurrence
  { id: 1, value_1: 2, value_2: 3 },  // 3 times value 3
  { id: 2, value_1: 3, value_2: 4 },  // 1 time  value 4
  { id: 3, value_1: 4, value_2: 3 },  // 3 times value 3
  { id: 4, value_1: 5, value_2: 2 },  // 2 times value 2
  { id: 5, value_1: 6, value_2: 3 },  // 3 times value 3
  { id: 6, value_1: 7, value_2: 2 },  // 2 times value 2
];
```

The challenge is how to determine the current frequency count of each same `value_2` value within/over the entire array.

**And unlike the above code's comment**, the expected result is an array where each item features the current frequency count of its `value_2` value, assigned to an additional `value_3` property ...

```
const array = [                       // expected:
  { id: 1, value_1: 2, value_2: 3 },  // value_3: 1 (1st occurrence of 3)
  { id: 2, value_1: 3, value_2: 4 },  // value_3: 1 (1st occurrence of 4)
  { id: 3, value_1: 4, value_2: 3 },  // value_3: 2 (2nd occurrence of 3)
  { id: 4, value_1: 5, value_2: 2 },  // value_3: 1 (1st occurrence of 2)
  { id: 5, value_1: 6, value_2: 3 },  // value_3: 3 (3rd occurrence of 3)
  { id: 6, value_1: 7, value_2: 2 },  // value_3: 2 (2nd occurrence of 2)
];
```

I found a solution to add `value_3` as new key into the object but I have problems finding a way to iterate through the array in order to determine each item's current frequency count of `value_2`.

Comment: If you actually tried any JavaScript, you need to post it as a [mcve], if not your question will be closed.

Comment: From your updated question, your question has been different between your 1st question and your updated question. In this case, I think that my answer was not useful for your actual expected result. I apologize for my poor English skill. So, I have to delete my answer. I apologize that I cannot notice that your question was different from your actual expected question.

Answer (score 0):

A single [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) task is capable of computing the `result` without mutating the original `array` it is operating upon.

One does achieve this by passing an object as [*initial value*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#how_reduce_works_with_an_initial_value) to the `reduce` method's 2nd argument. This object features two entries, the `counts` object as grouped counts lookup and the `result` array which references as final result an array, similar to the originally operated array, where each item features the additional `value_3` property with its correct consecutive count-value.

With each iteration one does either access or create a `value_2` specific count entry. The value of `value_2` does serve as (counts) group specific key. In case the `value_2` specific counter did not yet exist, it gets created and immediately assigned zero/`0` as its initial count value ...

```
let currentCount = (counts[key] ??= 0);
```

The latter gets achieved by utilizing the [*nullish coalescing assignment operator / `??=`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment).

Right after the immediately incremented `currentCount` gets assigned as update to the `value_2` specific counter. The only thing which still needs to be done is the creation of the currently processed `item`'s copy with the augmented `value_3` property which gets assigned the up-to-date `currentCount` value ...

```js
const array = [                       // expected augmentation:
  { id: 1, value_1: 2, value_2: 3 },  // value_3: 1
  { id: 2, value_1: 3, value_2: 4 },  // value_3: 1
  { id: 3, value_1: 4, value_2: 3 },  // value_3: 2
  { id: 4, value_1: 5, value_2: 2 },  // value_3: 1
  { id: 5, value_1: 6, value_2: 3 },  // value_3: 3
  { id: 6, value_1: 7, value_2: 2 },  // value_3: 2
];

const { result } = array
  .reduce(({ counts, result }, item) => {

    const { value_2: key } = item;

    let currentCount = (counts[key] ??= 0);
    counts[key] = ++currentCount;

    result
      .push({
        ...item,
        value_3: currentCount,
      });

    return { counts, result }

  }, { counts: {}, result: [] });

console.log({ array, result });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

The above approach could be implemented as solution which does mutate the original `array`. Here one would not only use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), but also an anonymous [*function expression*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#description) (and **not an** [*arrow function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)) in order to pass as the `forEach` method's 2nd [`thisArg`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#parameters) argument an initially empty `counts` object which is/becomes the callback function's `this` context ...

```js
const array = [                       // expected augmentation:
  { id: 1, value_1: 2, value_2: 3 },  // value_3: 1
  { id: 2, value_1: 3, value_2: 4 },  // value_3: 1
  { id: 3, value_1: 4, value_2: 3 },  // value_3: 2
  { id: 4, value_1: 5, value_2: 2 },  // value_3: 1
  { id: 5, value_1: 6, value_2: 3 },  // value_3: 3
  { id: 6, value_1: 7, value_2: 2 },  // value_3: 2
];

array
  .forEach(function (item) {

    const counts = this;
    const { value_2: key } = item;

    let currentCount = (counts[key] ??= 0);
    item.value_3 = counts[key] = ++currentCount;

  }, {});

console.log({ array });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```